# Как запустить простое веб-приложение?

Tags: java

Изучая пример веб-приложения на Java, возник следующий вопрос: как именно его запустить. [В данном примере](http://goo.gl/eJmlsV), не сочтите за рекламу, реализована передача файлов в рамках локальной сети. Запуск приложения осуществляется через команду:

```
java -cp . UploadServer <номер порта>
```

Для того чтобы узнать номер порта, в консоли набрал команду ipconfig:

[image: ipconfig]

но будучи, скажем, новичком в данном вопросе понял здесь, увы, немногое.

Вопрос, как правильно определить номер порта 'сервера' и что следует ввести в браузере 'клиента', чтобы программа корректно заработала?

Comment: Список открытых портов - команда netstat -a или netstat -n -a работает шустрее, потому что -n отключает долгую функцию определения имени хоста по его ип-адресу. А веб-приложения делаются по-разному. И запускаются тоже по-разному.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Попробую сейчас с netstat..

Comment: Запрос, наконец, полностью заработал. Еще раз большое спасибо.